# How do I ensure that the box highlighting the headings does not go over the length of the screen in CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, padding

Can someone help me with my problem please?

When hovering over some headings I have my sub-menu appear, which is fine, but the box highlighting the headings in the main menu bar also stretches the length of the screen and this is the problem. I don't want it to stretch the length of the screen.

I have experimented with the padding-bottom element reducing the size and it does solve my problem but creates another one.  By reducing the padding-bottom to anything less that what is shown in my code sample it also makes selecting the sub-menu headings difficult. When you try to select sub-menu it immediately disappears.

Here's a image to explain my problem better:

[image]

```
ul.topmenu li.submenu:hover {

     padding-bottom: 30em;
     background-color : #ccc;
}
```

Thank you for your help in this matter.

Comment: Can you put your code up on jsfiddle.net or paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you we need to see your html and css code (jsfiddle?)... It seems that the problem is your html markup, and main menu styles more than the submenu itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my CSS code for my problem.

```
ul.topmenu, ul.topmenu ul {
display: block;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #c00;
border: 7px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-radius:1em;

}


ul.topmenu li {

display: inline;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin: 200px;
padding : 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}


ul.topmenu li ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 1.5em;
visibility: hidden;
width: 10em;
background-color : #fff;
border : 5px solid #fc0;
border-right-style: dotted;
border-left-style: dotted;
border-top: 1;
}


ul.topmenu a {
 color : #ffffff;
 text-align:center;
}


ul.topmenu li ul li {

display: block;
width: 90%;
margin : 0px 0px 5px 0px;
background-color: #fff;
}



ul.topmenu li ul li a {
display: block;

padding: 0 0 0 0%;

color: #000;

font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-transform: capitalize;
}


ul.topmenu li.submenu:hover {

 padding-bottom: 30em;
 /*background-color : #ccc;*/
}



ul.topmenu li.submenu:hover ul {
 /*left: 0;*/
 visibility: visible;
}


ul.topmenu li.submenu:hover ul li {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}



ul.topmenu li.submenu:hover ul li:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```